# Max# of Children per Parent?

Tags: account

Is there a maximum number of Child accounts you can you have for a 'Parent Account'?

Answer (score 1):

As a best practice the documentation says that you shouldn't have more than 10K child records in a master detail relationship. Please see the link       http://resources.docs.salesforce.com/198/16/en-us/sfdc/pdf/salesforce_app_limits_cheatsheet.pdf

Comment: yes - but I believe Account - Parent Account is a hierarchy relationship, not master-detail

Comment: Thank you both.  I did notice the master - detail limit of 10K.  And my question is with regards to the Parent - Sub Acct or Child relationship.  Has anyone had experience with over 1 or 1.5K children? I appreciate all responses.